# How do I add the appcompat library to an android project in netbeans?

Tags: android, netbeans

I have the support libraries installed via the SDK manager.

I have copied the C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat folder to my projects libs folder.

I have added the \tools folder of the sdk to my command line path. I have then run

```
android update project --path . --library C:\Users\srayner\dev\android\AndroidTest1\libs\appcompat
```

But now netbeans gives me this error;

Failed to resolve library path: C:\Users\srayner\dev\android\AndroidTest1\libs\appcompat

What is the correct method to setup an android support library with resouses in netbeans?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have successfully build and added the appcompat project in NetBeans.

1. Create a new android project in netbeans - I called mine "appcompat".
2. Build your new project just make sure it can be successfully build.
3. Delete everything inside the src directory and rebuild. My project just contained the default MainActivity that was created by NetBeans. You don't need it.
4. Navigate to your android sdk install directory
   "androidSdkPath\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat and copy all
   the contents within that folder
5. Paste the copied contents to the android project that you
   created in step 1 (again mine was named as appcompat).
6. Very important - Open project.properties and ensure that the "target" property matches the following: "target=android-21"
7. Build your project and Voila... you should be all set.
8. If you are still having issues compiling the project that will be using the appcompat library, change your project library properties target=android-21"