# How to add recyclerview dependency to netbeans android project

Tags: java, android, netbeans, ant

I want to add the Android v7 support libraries and dependencies, specifically support for RecyclerView, to my Android NetBeans project which is using Ant for building. How do I do that? Sorry if this is a duplicate question, I couldn't find an exact answer. Please give clear steps where applicable. I have already updated and downloaded the support libs via Android SDK.

Comment: On a side note, do you a strong reason for using Netbeans for android development? Why not to use android studio (official IDE)? Moreover, the support for other IDEs is taken off by Google.

Comment: I just prefer using it, and also, the project is under a tight schedule, so I cannot spare time to try out a new IDE as of now

Comment: Fair enough. Did you try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27576821/4350275

Comment: Have been trying it for the past few hours, but its now giving me a new error I can't resolve yet: ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView" on path: DexPathList...

Comment: Would you believe the issue was with how the RecyclerView was being referenced in the XML? The official site says one should refer to it as : `<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView ... />`, but my app refused that until I changed it to `<View ... class="android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView" ... />`, which I found from [this page](http://javatechig.com/android/android-recyclerview-example). I wonder why yet that is the official doc from Android